# Script in /etc/init.d/ does not run in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: bash, 15.04, scripts, sysv

I have a script which simply echos current time and appends the output to a file. Below is the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Filename: /etc/init.d/bootlog
#Bash script to record a timestamp.
echo "Time: `date`" >> /home/foo/Documents/.boot_log
exit
```

I wanted to run this script every time my computer booted to runlevel 2, so I placed the above script in `/etc/init.d/` directory with execute permission for `root`.

```
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/bootlog 
-rwx------ 1 root root 161 Jan 12 11:02 /etc/init.d/bootlog
$
```

Next, I added the required symlink as below.

```
$ cd /etc/rc2.d/
$ sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/bootlog S06bootlog
$ sudo ls -l /etc/rc2.d/S06bootlog 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jan 12 12:34 /etc/rc2.d/S06bootlog -> /etc/init.d/bootlog
$
```

After doing the above steps I was expecting the script to run in my next reboot. However the script is NOT running during boot. I can see that because the `.boot_log` file is not created.

```
$ cd /home/foo/Documents/
$ sudo ls -l -a .boot_log
ls: cannot access .boot_log: No such file or directory
$
```

Is there any step I missed ? Or anything I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you did something wrong when looking for the file.

When you ran `cd /home/foo/Documents/` and then `ls -l -a .boot_log` you were attempting to find that file in the `/home/foo/Documents/` folder.

However, your *script* is storing it in your home directory (`/home/foo/`), as per `>> /home/foo/.boot_log`. Try running `ls -la .boot_log` in `/home/foo/` and the file should show up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had made a typo while posting the question. The script is redirecting to `>> /home/foo/Documents/.boot_log`.  I have corrected the question.

Comment: Ah. I see. Well, in that case, have you marked the script as executable? `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/bootlog`?

Comment: yes . it has +x permission.

Comment: Hrm. I'm out of ideas then, unfortunately :(  Try running `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/bootlog`, that's all I have